# Graphite and GUnicorn - Config issue or path issue

Tags: python, wsgi, gunicorn, graphite

I've been trying to get Graphite to run via GUnicorn (eventually proxied via nginx), however I have tried just about everything to startup the app and have been unable to get past errors similar to the following.

```
(graphite)/opt/graphite/conf gunicorn --bind=127.0.0.1:8080 graphite.wsgi:app
2014-03-03 17:02:14 [312] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2014-03-03 17:02:14 [312] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8080 (312)
2014-03-03 17:02:14 [312] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-03-03 17:02:14 [317] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 317
2014-03-03 17:02:14 [317] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/graphite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/graphite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/opt/graphite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/opt/graphite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/opt/graphite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/opt/graphite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named graphite.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/graphite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/graphite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/opt/graphite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/opt/graphite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/opt/graphite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/opt/graphite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named graphite.wsgi
2014-03-03 17:02:14 [317] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 317)
2014-03-03 17:02:14 [312] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-03-03 17:02:14 [312] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I've tried running in different directories (root dir, conf dir, webapp dir, etc.). I've tried running with the gunicorn_django helper. I *can* get it to boot using the development server: `opt/graphite/bin/run-graphite-devel-server.py --port=8080 /opt/graphite`

I've installed everything via virtualenv and pip and simply copied the graphite.wsgi.example file to graphite.wsgi in the `conf` dir. Looks like this:

```
(graphite)/opt/graphite/conf cat graphite.wsgi.example
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/opt/graphite/webapp')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'graphite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

# READ THIS
# Initializing the search index can be very expensive, please include
# the WSGIImportScript directive pointing to this script in your vhost
# config to ensure the index is preloaded before any requests are handed
# to the process.
from graphite.logger import log
log.info("graphite.wsgi - pid %d - reloading search index" % os.getpid())
import graphite.metrics.search
(graphite)/opt/graphite/conf
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

This is undoubtably the wrong way to do it, but I had the same issue and I got past it by:

```
mv /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi.example /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/graphite_wsgi.py
cd /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite
gunicorn graphite_wsgi:application
```

Your issue might just be using 'app' instead of the variable 'application' so give that a short first.

Good luck!